# How to forward a calendar item without notifying organizer

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I want to forward all calendar items within a certain date range to a specific email address without notifying the organizer.

Is there a way to do this using VBA code? I have the below code to not notify the meeting organizer but need to modify to forward all calendar items to a specific email address?

Also note I cannot forward as icalendar. I have a script which forwards emails when moved to a specific folder, however i cannot seem to convert or move meeting invites into the normal inbox folder.

```
Sub ForwardMeetingInvitation()
    Dim olSel As Selection
    Dim olMeeting As MeetingItem
    Dim olFWMeeting As MeetingItem
    Dim Recip As String

    Set olSel = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Set olMeeting = olSel.Item(1)
    'Replace with your own desired recipient's email address
    Recip = "pirate@fakemail.com"
 
    Set olFWMeeting = olMeeting.Forward
    With olFWMeeting
         .Recipients.Add (Recip)
         .Attachments.Add olMeeting
         .Display
    End With
 
    Set olSel = Nothing
    Set olMeeting = Nothing
    Set olFWMeeting = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: your script doesn't work, it still shows the mark of  "When you forward this meeting, a meeting forward notification will be sent to the organizer."